# With knowing just 2 points that represent opposing corners, how to determine if a point input by the user is inside the rectangle

Tags: java, eclipse, position, coordinates, rectangles

I searched for questions already asked on this, but it seems they just covered if one knew 3 points. However, what if you only have two points and you know that these two points represent opposing corners on the rectangle? knowing this how could you determine if a user inputs any point, if this point is inside the rectangle? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially here's what you need to do:

1. Based on your points 1 and 3, construct the other two points 2 and 4
   to complete the rectangle definition.
2. Take in the user-input point, we'll call it 5.
3. Calculate the area made by triangles for all P(1,2,5), P(1,4,5), P(2,3,5), P(3,4,5) and add these areas together.
4. If any of these areas is 0, then you know the point is ON the rectangle perimeter. If the area sum is greater than the area of the
   rectangle, the point is outside the rectangle. If it is equal to the
   rectangle area, it is inside.

[image]

Comment: Ok, makes sense, why would you calculate the area of triangles though?

Comment: It's a technique commonly used to check if a point is within the confines of a rectangle. The area of the rectangle should be equal to the area of the four triangles made as described (you can check it on a piece of paper). If the areas are not equal (with some rounding error taken into account) then your point is not inside the rectangle.

Comment: ok, gotcha. also the points can be arbitrary, as long as it is essentially the same combination you used in calculating the triangles areas?

Comment: Yep. As long as you define which two points define your rectangle and which point you're trying to determine lies inside the rectangle, you're fine. All points can be arbitrary. I'll put an image in my post to illustrate.

Comment: There you go - hopefully that helps.

Comment: yeah it does. appreciate your help.

Comment: How can you complete the rectangle definition if you assume, as the picture shows, a rectangle tilted at an arbitrary angle?

Comment: Draw a line between points d and b and then construct right angle triangles on either side of the line (that would be one way).

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is 2D. So you have two points given which represents the bottomleftcorner and the toprightcorner. You can now calculate the missing points.
For example here some random points:

```
blc(1,1) and trc(4,2)
```

You can now calculate the height and width difference and construct the missing points.

```
topleftcorner(1,2) and bottomrightcorner(4,1)
```

Now you have a fully rectangle and you can check the given input if it is inside the area or not.